# ::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator not working on Android

Tags: html, css, webkit

```css
.date::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
.date::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    display: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="date" min="1946-01-01" max="2015-04-01" class="date" value="1946-01-01" required>
```

This works well on PC browsers, but on mobile only IOS works as expect. All Android browsers (Webview, Chrome, Firefox) can only hide the inner spin button, the calendar picker triangle is still visible.

Comment: did you find a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  background: none;
}
```

try this